# How to convert htmlagility.htmlnode[] to byte[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, html-agility-pack

```
string strEmailContent = "<div><span>hi</span><span>hello</span></div>"
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument imgString = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
imgString.LoadHtml(strEmailContent);
HtmlNode[] nodes = imgString.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span").ToArray();
```

In this storing span values in htmlagility htmlnode. I want to convert **htmlnode[]** in to **byte[]** for storing it into **Dictionary**.

Comment: Why? What you actually want to achieve as result?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i want to use this in Dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary<string, byte[]> linkedResources = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
                linkedResources.Add("img", byte[]);

Comment: Why not store the HtmlNode in the dictionary? I assume it's not the key?